# Undefined index error when saving content on metabox

Tags: custom-field, metabox, debug

I am trying to debug 'undefined index' errors on the WP backend when debug is set to TRUE. The offending lines are:

```
if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['pdwt_meta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
    return $post->ID;
}
```

Which I have then changed to check whether the value has been set by adding:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['pdwt_meta_noncename']) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['pdwt_meta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
    return $post->ID;
}
```

The addition makes the error disappear but when I enter information on the custom field, it does not save.

This is how the custom field has been set:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="pdwt_meta_noncename" id="pdwt_meta_noncename" value="' .
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';
```

Here is the `save_post` part:

```
foreach ($pdwt_meta as $key => $value) { // loop through the $pdwt_meta array
    if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; // make sure the data isn't stored twice
    $value = implode(',', (array)$value); // if $value is in an array, make it a comma seperated value
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // if the custom field already has a value
        update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
    } else { // AND IF IT DOESN'T ALREADY HAVE A VALUE
        add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
    }
    if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // DELETE IF IT'S EMPTY
}     
add_action('save_post', 'pdwt_save_meta', 1, 2); // SAVE THE CUSTOM FIELDS
```

I did not write this specific part of the theme. Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. Till can't find any solution. For the volunteers, here's the exact tuts link that the process is revised: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields--wp-23259

Comment: @mayeenul Ah! thanks for this! Have you tried applying the solution suggested on the comments on this tutorial.  It looks like I was missing a line on the `save_post` part by the look of it
`for this line:
wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'custom_meta_box_nonce' );

In function save_meta() replace this line:
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))

for this line:
if (!isset($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))`

Comment: it worked. You can add this as answer mentioning the comment as a link with a basic explanation, and then can accept it as an answer. It'll help others. :)

Comment: Great you got it working @MayeenulIslam.  Have now added it as an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Resolved by following comment on Tutsplus Tutorial (link included):

In function `save_meta()`, replace this line:

```
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))
```

with this line:

```
if (!isset($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['custom_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__)))
```

See full comment [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields--wp-23259#comment-938323026).